# Call returned array list values when calling function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am beginner in ASP.NET and C# programming. I have two clasees Phone and Report.
I want to call function LookupNumber(Phone p) in Default.aspx.cs file and to get each returned value of array list, displaying returned values in labels controls. 
But I get this error:

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'PhoneLookup.Models.Phone.LookupNumber(Phone.Models.Phone)'   C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\Phone\Phone\Default.aspx.cs   24  26  Phone
>
> Error 2   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'PhoneLookup.Models.Phone.LookupNumber(Phone.Models.Phone)'   C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\Phone\Phone\Default.aspx.cs   24  26  Phone
>
> Error 3   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'PhoneLookup.Models.Phone.LookupNumber(Phone.Models.Phone)'   C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\Phone\Phone\Default.aspx.cs   24  26  Phone

Here is my source  code:

```
// Report.cs

namespace PhoneLookup.Models
{
    public class Report
    {
        private String _name_surname;
        private String _address;
        private String _area_code;
        private String _exchange;
        private String _service_provider;

        public Report()
        {
            _name_surname = String.Empty; _address = String.Empty; _area_code = String.Empty; 
            _exchange = String.Empty; _service_provider = String.Empty; 
        }

        public String name_surname { get; set; }
        public String address { get; set; }
        public String area_code { get; set; }
        public String exchange { get; set; }
        public String service_provider { get; set; }
    }
}

// Phone.cs Class
namespace PhoneLookup.Models
{
    public class Phone
    {
        private Int16 _phone_number;

        public Phone()
        {
            _phone_number = -1;
        }

        public Int16 phone_number { get; set; }

        public Report[] LookupNumber(Phone p)
        {
            List<Report> lst = new List<Report>();
            MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(constr);
            Conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand Cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Reports WHERE phone_number = @pn", Conn);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pn", p.phone_number);
            MySqlDataReader Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
            lst.Add(new Report()
            {
                name_surname = Reader["name_surname"]).ToString(),
                address = Reader["address"].ToString(),
                area_code = Reader["area_code"].ToString(),
                exchange = Reader["exchange"].ToString(),
                service_provider = Reader["service_provider"].ToString(),
            });

}
            return lst.ToArray();
        }
    }
}


// Default.aspx.cs

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Phone p = new Phone();
     p.phone_number = Convert.ToInt16(q.Text);
// display name surname
     Report[] ns = Phone.LookupNumber(p).Select(x => x.name_surname).ToArray();
// display adddress
     Report[] ad = Phone.LookupNumber(p).Select(x => x.address).ToArray();
// display service provider
     Report[] sp = Phone.LookupNumber(p).Select(x => x.service_provider).ToArray();
     Label1.Text = ns.ToString();
     Label2.Text = ad.ToString();
     Label3.Text = sp.ToString();
}
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: Looks like you need to `Phone` instance instead of it's type. Like `var p = new Phone();` and call `p.LookupNumber(...)` etc. Or change this `LookupNumber` method to `static` like `public static Report[] LookupNumber`.

Comment: @SonerGönül       
I change , but I get this error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'Phone.Models.Report[]'

Answer (score 1):

look at your code line below

```
Report[] ns = Phone.LookupNumber(p).Select(x => x.name_surname).ToArray();
```

First `LookupNumber(p)` is an instance method and not a static method and so you should call it like `p.LookupNumber(p)` (or) declare it as static method by prefixing `static` keyword.

Second, the LINQ call `Select(x => x.name_surname).ToArray()` will return a string array `string[]` cause you are selecting a specific field which is of `string` type but you are storing it as `Report[]`. You should rather make it like

```
string[] ns = Phone.LookupNumber(p).Select(x => x.name_surname).ToArray();
```

Per your comment:

Yes and that's because you are calling `ToString()` on a collection obejct as can be depicted below.

```
Label1.Text = ns.ToString();
```

If you really want to show in lebel then probably get the first element in the array and show it as below (or) use a different control like `ListBox`

```
Label1.Text = ns.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: string[] ns = Phone.LookupNumber(p).Select(x => x.name_surname).ToArray();  returns to me :  System.String[]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
    public Report[] LookupNumber(Phone p)
```

to:

```
    public static Report[] LookupNumber(Phone p)
```

Comment: I change , but I get this error:                                                                                 Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'Phone.Models.Report[]'

Comment: The conversion problem is caused by your LINQ statement. You are doing a select which is returning a string. So, the LINQ statement will return an array of strings.

Comment: Additionally, as note. It would be better to call the LookupNumber function once to get the report on the phone number, and then query that retrieved report.

Comment: How can I get values of arraylist without Linq statement trouble ?

Comment: Change the types of ns, ad, and sp to "string[]".
You will also need to change the logic for setting the labels' text. You are trying to convert the information for multiple strings to a single string. This requires formatting or redesigning your page.

Answer (score 0):

Should you being using "where" instead of "select"?

> Report[] ns = Phone.LookupNumber(p).where(x => x.name_surname ==
>   ?).ToArray();

By the looks of it, if you are trying to "select" a field, the type of that field will be return (i.e. string).